# Write to files with dynamic file names?

Tags: python, bigdata

I need to split a large txt file (about 100GB, **1 billion rows**) by DATE. The file looks like this

```
ID*DATE*company
1111*201101*geico
1234*201402*travelers
3214*201003*statefarm
...
```

Basically there are 60 months so I should be getting 60 sub-files. My Python script is

```
with open("myBigFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
        claim = line.split("*")
        with open("DATE-"+str(claim[1])+".txt", "a") as fy:
            fy.write(claim[0]+"*"+claim[2]+"\n")
```

Now since the number of records is huge, this runs too slow because it needs to open/close file for every row. So I'm thinking about first open 60 sub-files and then scan the file, write each row to corresponding sub-file. **The sub-files are not closed until all the rows are scanned**. However since python automatically close the file whenever the reference is removed (http://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/), I have to use some dynamic file name, something like

```
claim[1].write(claim[0]+"*"+claim[2]+"\n")
```

Note that you can't name a `fy` and `fy.write(claim[0]+"*"+claim[2]+"\n")` because that will close the file whenever `fy` is changed. Is that possible in Python? Thanks!

Comment: Could be a cut-paste thing, but your code is not indented properly I think, after the `for line in f:...` Fix it if requied.

Comment: Build a dictionary of file handles, indexed by the file name.  Build a file name, open the file, and save the file handle in the dictionary.

Comment: @PatJones reading 100GB into memory?

Comment: @PatJones that's likely impractical for the given file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
with open("myBigFile.txt") as f:
subfiles = {}
for line in f: 
    claim = line.split("*")
    if not str(claim[1]) in subfiles:
        subfiles[str(claim[1])] = open("DATE-" + str(claim[1]) + ".txt", "a")
    subfile[str(claim[1])].write(claim[0]+"*"+claim[2]+"\n")
```

I believe this should do it.

Just to mention, I have currently not placed a limit on the number of files opened at a given moment. To implement  that simply check the size of the list using 'len()' and close all files or a few files.

Comment: That's a lot of look-ups if your doing it for a billion rows.

Comment: You need to close the files when you're finished.

Comment: I know, but that's what the OP explicitly wants. "The sub-files are not closed until all the rows are scanned"

Comment: Yes, you don't close them ever.

Comment: I did mention in the text that one could check the number of open files and close them according to the wish. I believe I can leave some work for the OP.

Comment: I thought so too, but the OP used str() so I thought it might have been for a reason.

Comment: Give the split line objects names so you don't have to look them up by index: `id, date, company = line.split('*')`

Comment: Look I appreciate your comments but the base code isn't mine. I wasn't here to optimise OP's code or point out mistakes. I just helped him with the problem he mentioned. If you want to point out things I haven't changed, pls do it on the question. And if you have so much to add please post an answer of your own. I am not explaining myself further to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Swakeert Jain That just worked! Just so simple...Thanks! BTW, how can I close all the files besides del(subfiles) ?

Comment: @JasonLuo iterating over the subfiles array and closing each files individually would be the best way. for s in subfiles: s.close(). After the loop you can reinitiate the list to remove the keys as well. subfiles = {}. This can be done when len(subfiles) >= 60.

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks to both of you. Swakeert has solved the major problem but yes for this big data I need to do more optimization so Peter's suggestions are also very useful to such a beginner as me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module to simplify slightly, and use a dictionary to store the file objects:

```
import csv

with open("myBigFile.txt") as big_file:
    reader = csv.reader(big_file, delimiter='*')
    subfiles = {}

    for id, date, company in reader:
        try:
            subfile = subfiles[date]
        except KeyError:
            subfile = open('DATE-{}.txt'.format(date), 'a')
            subfiles[date] = subfile

        subfile.write('{}*{}\n'.format(id, company))

    for subfile in subfiles.values():
        subfile.close()
```

Comment: Seems `reader = csv.reader(big_file, separator='*')` didn't work, I changed it to `reader = csv.reader(big_file, delimiter='*')` but the same.

Comment: Fixed, sorry was from memory (defective)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will close the file handles as part of a context manager, unlike the other answers this also closes the subfiles when an error happens :-)

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def file_writer():
    fp = {}

    def write(line):
        id, date, company = line.split('*')
        outdata = "{}*{}\n".format(id, company)
        try:
            fp[date].write(outdata)
        except KeyError:
            fname = 'DATE-{}.txt'.format(date)
            fp[date] = open(fname, 'a')    # should it be a+?
            fp[date].write(outdata)

    yield write

    for f in fp.values():
        f.close()


def process():
    with open("myBigFile.txt") as f:
        with file_writer() as write:
            for i, line in enumerate(f):
                try:
                    write(line)
                except:
                    print('the error happened on line %d [%s]' % (i, line))
```

I don't know if there is anything more that can be done speed-wise on a single processor/disk. You can always split the file into n chunks and use n processes to process a chunk each (where n is the number of separate disks you have available..)

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn actually splitting by DATE is already a 'divide and conquer'.

Comment: 100GB is still pretty big, especially if you haven't implemented any restart logic. Based on my, rather limited, experience, I would suggest splitting the file into sizes you can fit in memory (and buy lots of memory <wink>).

Comment: I'm trying your code but `fp[date].write(outdata)` always print out the length of the string `outdata` when writing. How can I suppress this? Thanks  @thebjorn

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior.

Comment: Can you run   `fy = open("tmp.txt", "a")` then `fy.write('123'+'abc')`?  It won't happen when I run iteratively python3 IDE (Rodeo) or python2, but when I run it on a Linux server (python3 with no IDE) it always print out the length of string. I suppose there is a way to manually supress this annoying print-out, given the big data I have? PS: I'd like to open another question but seems I asked too many questions these days. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It's the return value (although not sure why it would be printed). You can get rid of it by assigning it to a throw-away variable: `_ = fp[date].write(outdata)`

Comment: Ok... That just seems so weired to me. Thanks

Comment: If you run the file (instead of entering commands at the Python prompt) this would not happen.